# JavaFX adding and removing Node from BorderPane

Tags: java, eclipse, javafx, fxml

I want to programmatically add and remove side menu in `BorderPane`.
Problem is when I add a `Node`, it is not visible.
`BorderPane` and `StackPane` are defined in FXML file.

I want to do something like this:

```
StackPane temp = (StackPane) borderPane.getChildren().get(1);
borderPane.getChildren().remove(1);
borderPane.getChildren().add(0, temp);
```

I have tried `borderPane.requestLayout()` but it is not working.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use [`setRight`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/layout/BorderPane.html#setRight-javafx.scene.Node-) or `setLeft`, `setTop`, `setBottom`, `setCenter` methods to add `Node`s to different parts and also [`getRight`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/layout/BorderPane.html#getRight--), `getLeft`, `getTop`, `getBottom`, `getCenter` to retrieve the currently assigned `Node`. The set methods can be also used to remove the currently set `Node` by passing `null` value.

**Example:**

Imagine that you have a `BorderPane` that has a `StackPane` placed on the right side, and you want to move it to the left side.

```
StackPane temp = (StackPane) borderPane.getRight(); // Casting is unnecessary
borderPane.setRight(null);
borderPane.setLeft(temp);
```

Comment: Thank you, that is what I was looking for.

Comment: How come I am advised to use static when I use `borderPane.setAligment()`? I would have preferred to position my nodes that way

Answer (score 0):

It's to simple to remove node from border pane. Declare border pane ID and using that id select children node and remove specified side(left,right,top,bottom) by below code.

```
    @FXML
    private BorderPane borderPane;

    @Override
    public void initialize(URL location, ResourceBundle resources) {
        borderPane.getChildren().remove(borderPane.getLeft());
        borderPane.getChildren().remove(borderPane.getRight());
    }
```

Comment: Explain the author what exactly are you doing and why his approach doesn't work.

Comment: @mentallurg please check now

Comment: Not it is clear what you mean, what your code is doing. I don't say anything about the solution. Let the others check it.